# Include HTML as part of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to include some HTML and JavaScript as the value to a string member in a JSON object. Has anyone got some JS code handy that would do the necessary escaping so that the html can be included? Alternatively I could convert it to Base64 but then I would still need to do some escaping.

So if anyone has got any JS to do something that would escape any HTML (which may contain JavaScript) so that it is properly escaped, I would be greatly appreciative. No point rolling my own if there is something out there that does this already.

```
{
    "my_object": {
    "html": "<<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"some_ad.png\"\/><h3>&quot;Hot&quot; Items<ul \/><\/div>",

        "item_id": 1234,

    "click_action":"/logAction?id=1234&type=click&info=blah",

        "icon":"http://my.images.com/icons/icon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be the consequence of a confusion appearing in the "JSON object" expression.

There are two different concepts :

- JavaScript object
- JSON string

There's nothing that can be legitimately called "JSON object", [JSON is a string based exchange format](http://json.org).

When you build the object, you don't have any escaping to do, simply do `myObject.myHtml = someValue;`. When building a literal object, simply do

```
var myObject = {
    html : '<div class="ad_box [...] </div>',
    [...]
};
```

And in a second step, get the JSON string with

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```